# Globally change appbar shape in flutter

Tags: flutter

I can change app bar shape in flutter

```
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        elevation: 0.0,
        shape: ContinuousRectangleBorder(
          borderRadius: const BorderRadius.only(
            bottomLeft: Radius.circular(80.0),
          ),
        ),
        title: Text('AppBar'),
      ),
    );
```

I dont want each time I create `Scaffold` pass my AppBar to it , I want to do it globally (may be in theme we can)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can create a separate widget which returns custom appbar for you like below.

```
class CustomAppBar extends PreferredSize {
  @override
  Size get preferredSize {
    return new Size.fromHeight(56.0);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return AppBar(
      elevation: 0.0,
      shape: ContinuousRectangleBorder(
        borderRadius: const BorderRadius.only(
          bottomLeft: Radius.circular(80.0),
        ),
      ),
      title: Text('AppBar'),
    );
  }
}
```

Now you can assign this widget to appbar.

Comment: It is too cumbersome , each time pass it to scaffold, I have too many scaffold , I am searching for few lines solution

Comment: i don't think it is cumbersome, because as you use appbar you have to use this widget. what is the issue in this?

Comment: Yes you are right, But I think may be there is a better way to do this without creating new widget

Comment: Another question : how to revert it back to default shape / What's the default widget of Appbar shape.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to use the `GlobalUtil`class on which you create the `AppBar` and use in all over the class like below

**GlobalUtil.dart**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import 'colors.dart';


class GlobalUtil {

  static Widget showAppBar(BuildContext context, String msg, String path) {
    return AppBar(
      centerTitle: true,
      title: Text(
        msg,
        style: TextStyle(
            color: ColorConst.TEXT_DARK_GREY_COLOR,  /// USE THE COLOR AS PER YOUR REQUIREMENT
            fontFamily: 'Medium', /// USE THE FONT FAMILY AS PER YOUR REQUIREMENT
            fontSize: Dimens.TEXT_EXTRA_EXTRA_LARGE),////// USE THE DIMENSION OF TEXT AS PER YOUR REQUIREMENT
      ),
        actions: [
          new IconButton(
            icon: new Image.asset("YOUR_ICON_PATH",height: 20.0,width: 20.0,),
            onPressed: () => {


            },
          )
        ],
      leading: Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(8),
          child: new IconButton(
            // icon: new Icon(iconData, color: Colors.black),
            icon: new Image.asset(path),
            onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).pop(),
          )),
      backgroundColor: Colors.PINK,
      elevation: 0.0,
    );

  }

}
```

And inside any class , you can use it as following

```
 GlobalUtil.showAppBar(context, "YOUR HEADING TEXT",
            "YOUR_ICON_FOR_BACK"),
```

Comment: Your solution is same as viren's solution , You just use static method, Just like theme I want to change my app bar easily with few lines of code , Assume I asked about "How can I change my buttons color globally?" I searched for "You can use ThemeData" but you answered "Create a custom widget or static method that return it"

Comment: @WebMaster Whats the problem in it.. You just use the same widget on all the screen on which you wanted with same effect